# Shopify: Adding customer[tags] on login form

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api

At registration i add a language tag using the customer[tags]

```
<input type="hidden" name="customer[tags]" value="lng:fr">
```

I added the same script to customer_login form to update old customer but it does not seem to work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add tags on login, only at register.

This is limitation set by Shopify.

If you like to create a tag on login you will be required to create a custom APP that will handle this, there is no default way to achieve this only liquid.